# Input figures from sub-folders

Tags: floats, input

I'm writing a big thesis using latex and I'm trying to keep organised.

**File-tree:**

> ../Thesis/mainfile.tex
>
> ../Thesis/Section1/section1.tex
>
> ../Thesis/Figures/figure1.png
>
> ../Thesis/Figures/figure1.tex

_

> **mainfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}%
\begin{document}
\input{Section1/section1.tex}
\end{document}
```

> **section1.tex**:

```
\input{Figures/figure1.tex}
\input{../Figures/figure1.tex}
\input{../../Figures/figure1.tex}
```

Tried these lines. None of them work.

> **figure1.tex**

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{../Figures/figure1.png}
\caption{This is Figure 1}
\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is how I call for the 'figure1.tex' from 'section1.tex'. I'm trying to input file one directory up and in another subfolder.
I keep getting this message.

File `../Figures/figure1.tex' not found.
 \input{../Figures/figure1.tex}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just tested it: LaTeX does not change to `Section1` directory, but stays in the main (Thesis) directory, so it should be `\input{Figures/figure1.tex}

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've tried to make the question clearer.

Comment: This has been solved. For some reason this works like a charm like I made it in the beginning.
'\input{Figures/figure1.tex}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory/File structure

> Thesis/Section1/section1.tex
>
> Thesis/Figures/figure1.tex

### main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{graphicx}%

\begin{document}

\input{Section1/section1}

\end{document}
```

### section1.tex

```
\section{First}

\input{Figures/figure1}
```

### figure1.tex

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: May be adding a comment about `\graphicspath` and `\input@path`?

Comment: @Manuel: Where should I add it -- in my solution? I never set those paths explicitly ;-)